# Primefaces media pdf parameters not set

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to set parameters for primefaces media pdf tag like below

```
<p:media id="event" value="#{observerMBean.event.streamedContent}" width="100%" height="100%" player="pdf" >
    <f:param name="view" value="fitH"></f:param>
    <f:param name="toolbar" value="0"></f:param>
    <f:param name="zoom" value="scale"></f:param>
</p:media>
```

But the parameter values are not reflecting in the PDF viewer. Is there any other way to pass parameters to set zoom and toolbar values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this resolved my issue

```
<f:param name="#toolbar" value="0"></f:param>
```

Comment: Hey, this is is great to know. Is the same true for the other params? Does it work with the latest PF version?

Comment: It does not work for IE. I have tried with PF 5.3 version.

Comment: For other parameters you need not use "#" . It works for other parameters as well.